# How to clean a sticky Magic Trackpad click?

Tags: magic-trackpad, macos

My magic trackpad seems to have gotten dirty in the button.

I've tried swabbing around the button with alcohol but I still, at times, have to lift the trackpad to release the mouse click.

Do you have any clever ways of cleaning it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Magic Trackpad 1 also lost its ability to unclick and I had to lift it up to get it to release. I tried various cleaning fixes but none worked for me. It seemed that there was no spring-back action left in the magicpad. I use the pad a lot in photoshop with lots of clicking and dragging so I guessed the spring had finally just worn out. However I found a solution on this website.

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Magic+Trackpad+Click+Adjustment/6171

It was more than I wanted to try, but I really need my magic pad to work as I had a big project on the go. The fix works well and I added little adjustment to the procedure. In step 3 where the adjustment screw is pointed out in the photo, the bar it is set in is also the spring that provides the un-clicking action of the pad. I gave the whole bar a gentle pull upwards, away from the pad, this put some spring back into the trackpad. The Magic trackpad now works perfectly again.

I also used 2 rubber self-sticking bumpers to replace the feet. These bumpers are often used on the back of picture frames to protect walls or under trays to to prevent scratching tables. The size I got were 8mil and fit perfectly. The added advantage to putting them on first is than you fine tune the screw adjustments you make to the trackpad before replacing the white back to the trackpad. This video shows put the bumpers on.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmO_G7Ct9k8

Final word of advice, gently warm the white back of the trackpad before removing it. A hair dryer works well and I just laid mine in the sun for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

Try some Goo-B-Gone or other citrus based cleaning fluid.

Answer (score 1):

I used an old, clean toothbrush and it worked perfect. I used a tiny bit of water, but I am sure it would work without that (in reflection i would try it first WITHOUT WATER as to not risk damage of the computer parts). I just flipped over the trackpad, pushed the button in and worked the toothbrush bristles into the seam all around it. I instantly could feel the button not sticking.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

- 1 or 2 cotton buds
- Isopropyl alcohol (IPA)

What you need to do:

- Put some Isopropyl alcohol on the end of the cotton bud.
- Rub the alcohol onto the offending button, being careful not to allow alcohol to enter into the case.

This worked for me, so I hope it will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

If your track pad is sticking means the click isn't released when your finger is lifted. Then all that I had to do is clean the bottom of the trackpad (with rubbing alcohol)!  Those are basically buttons which allow you to put even pressure to click. When the surface is dirty, the pressure is uneven.  Also clean the surface of the trackpad while you're at it.